# Remove "node" from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I´ve got these two methods im using to find a customer. How can I remove the customer I´ve just found from the list? I´m using arrayList
Heres my two methods:

```
public User findById(int id) 
{
    for (User u : list) 
    {
        if (u.getCustomerID() == id) 
        {
            return u;
        }
    }
    return null; // or empty User
}
```

And

```
public void findByID()
{
    int customer = Integer.parseInt(findCustomerField.getText());

    if(customer != 0)
    {
        User user = list.findById(customer);
        outputText.setText(user.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I remove the customer I´ve just found from the list?

It's as simply as calling the `remove` method:

```
list.remove(user);
```

However, that will need to go through the list again to find the entry.

If you want a remove-by-ID method, you can do that with the iterator:

```
public bool removeById(int userId) {
    for (Iterator<User> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        if (iterator.next().getCustomerID() == id) {
            iterator.remove();
            return true; // Found and removed
        } 
    }
    return false; // Not found
}
```